# Getting data between a date range

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm writing a program in Java where there is an Excel sheet with 3 users like:

```
user1
user2
uesr3
```

And their task is to process some products daily, and the data is stored in an Excel like below.

```
user  | product | date
user1 | 123     | 2/22/2016
user2 | 143     | 2/22/2016
user2 | 145     | 2/22/2016
user3 | 182     | 2/24/2016
user2 | 151     | 2/25/2016
```

And in my Java application, when I select a data range, I need to print the number of users worked on number of products in console.

Like if I select date range as `2/22/2016` -'2/22/2016'. It should show me

```
user1 - 1
user2 - 2
```

This is just a sample created, but in real there are around 1000 rows and counter would slowdown the process.

I'm sure that this can be done easily in JDBC, but I don't want to use a JDBC application. Can this be done using POI?

I'm using the below code to read from Excel.

```
 String excelFilePath = "Books.xlsx";
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                }
                System.out.print(" - ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();
```

Comment: have u even tried reading the excel yet.

Comment: Yes I'm able to reads the excel file. I'm using apachePOI

Comment: @Priyamal, updated my code with read class

Comment: Reading file is O(n). As you read them, filter them, count them in map (key would be users), values would be number of occurrences. You will still have O(n) execution time and as you finish reading data, you will have counts for each user.

Comment: not worth an answer, but the way we do it is converting dates to text with format like YYY-MM-DD to be able to compare strings; we had quite a lot of gotchas with excel date and locale management

Comment: Would opting for JDBC be a better option?